# Smallest rectangle outside two UIViews - ObjectiveC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I have two `UIView`s and I need to draw a rectangle (or) get the frame of the smallest rectangle outside both the `UIViews`. How can I get this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide some code or something to show you have had some sort of attempted at this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
CGRect smallestRectangle = CGRectUnion(view1.frame, view2.frame);
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_31), this function

> Returns the smallest rectangle that contains the two source rectangles.

Comment: much simpler :) didnt know this function existed

Comment: All functions in [CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) are pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

here are some steps that should work to find the rectangle you want

- find the left most origin.x... = new origin.x
- find the top most origin.y... = new origin.y
- find the largest (origin.x + size.width)... = new size.width
- find the largest (origin.y + size.height)... = new size.height